# How to split up the en.yml-file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

The idea would be to have one en.yml file for formtastic labels, one for hints, one for other I18n-Translations. Is that possible?

Comment: ok I guess this solves it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, as you found out yourself and as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files), you can have as many locale yml files as you wish, containing just subsets of your translations.

If you use subdirectories for separation, do not forget to adapt the standard rails I18n load path (also described there)